# At every launch Mail.app welcomes me and downloads my messages

Tags: mail.app

Every time I launch Mail.app it shows the (first launch) Welcome dialog and tells me that to use new feature sin Mail it has to download my messages. I have many many messages in there and I know that it is not redownloading them so what gives?

OSX current and fully patched.

I checked disk perms and found plenty of issues with iBook.app and some with java but nothing with mail - none the less it's about time for a RepairPerms so I'm running it and bounce Mail.app to see if that fixes it. Nope.

Console.app reports a slew of errors for Mail.app (only showing the ones since *after* I ran RepairPerms and bounced Mail.app twice).

> 3/24/14 2:40:50.226 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.510[182]: (com.apple.mail.28720[992]) Exited: Terminated: 15
>   3/24/14 2:41:01.033 PM Mail[2590]: Upgrading Library from 4.167 to 4.167
>   3/24/14 2:41:01.043 PM Mail[2590]: Plugin compatibility check failed for GrowlMail.mailbundle. The plugin's Info.plist must have a SupportedPluginCompatibilityUUIDs key whose value is an array of strings that contains the compatibility UUIDs for the supported versions of Mail. The compatibility UUID value is found in the PluginCompatibilityUUID key of Mail's Info.plist
>   3/24/14 2:41:01.044 PM Mail[2590]: Plugin compatibility check failed for ProxiMail.mailbundle. The plugin's Info.plist must have a SupportedPluginCompatibilityUUIDs key whose value is an array of strings that contains the compatibility UUIDs for the supported versions of Mail. The compatibility UUID value is found in the PluginCompatibilityUUID key of Mail's Info.plist
>   3/24/14 2:41:01.177 PM sandboxd[118]: ([2590]) Mail(2590) deny file-write-create /Library/Mail/Bundles (Disabled 3)
>   3/24/14 2:41:03.979 PM WindowServer[92]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Mail" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
>   3/24/14 2:41:04.149 PM WindowServer[92]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Mail" after 1.17 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
>   3/24/14 2:41:05.690 PM Mail[2590]: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)
>   3/24/14 2:42:03.140 PM Mail[2601]: Upgrading Library from 4.167 to 4.167
>   3/24/14 2:42:03.147 PM Mail[2601]: Plugin compatibility check failed for GrowlMail.mailbundle. The plugin's Info.plist must have a SupportedPluginCompatibilityUUIDs key whose value is an array of strings that contains the compatibility UUIDs for the supported versions of Mail. The compatibility UUID value is found in the PluginCompatibilityUUID key of Mail's Info.plist
>   3/24/14 2:42:03.148 PM Mail[2601]: Plugin compatibility check failed for ProxiMail.mailbundle. The plugin's Info.plist must have a SupportedPluginCompatibilityUUIDs key whose value is an array of strings that contains the compatibility UUIDs for the supported versions of Mail. The compatibility UUID value is found in the PluginCompatibilityUUID key of Mail's Info.plist
>   3/24/14 2:42:03.180 PM sandboxd[118]: ([2601]) Mail(2601) deny file-write-create /Library/Mail/Bundles (Disabled 3)
>   3/24/14 2:42:04.562 PM Mail[2601]: *** Assertion failure in +[MFMessageRouter junkMailRule], /SourceCache/Mail/Mail-1874/FrameworkTargets/MailFramework/Rules/MFMessageRouter.m:1440
>   rules must already be loaded
>   (
>       0   MailCore                            0x00007fff968e3c2c -[MCAssertionHandler _handleFailureWithPreamble:description:arguments:] + 141
>       1   MailCore                            0x00007fff968e3a9d -[MCAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 215
>       2   Mail                                0x00007fff8cca5246 +[MFMessageRouter junkMailRule] + 123
>       3   Mail                                0x00007fff8cc738b0 -[MFMailAccount junkMailboxCreateIfNeeded:] + 74
>       4   Mail                                0x00007fff8cc6ffcf +[MFMailAccount _specialMailboxesUsingSelector:] + 248
>       5   Mail                                0x00007fff8cc2c4f7 MFExcludedMailboxes + 158
>       6   Mail                                0x00007fff8cc2c5e5 +[MFLibrary createAllMailboxesSpotlightQueryWithQueryString:attributes:forUnreadCount:withMailboxExclusions:includeWhereFromsCriterion:] + 72
>       7   Mail                                0x00007fff8ccf333c -[MFSmartMailboxUnreadCountManager _updateSmartMailboxUnreadCountUsingSpotlight:useTotalCount:] + 501
>       8   Mail                                0x00007fff8ccf41da __91-[MFSmartMailboxUnreadCountManager updateMailboxesUnreadCountUsingSpotlight:useTotalCount:]_block_invoke + 158
>       9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8a5af0b5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 75
>       10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8a58e8a1 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 631
>       11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8a58e54b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64
>       12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff943eb2ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff943ef7ff _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 154
>       14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff943eb2ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff943ed09e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
>       16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff943ee193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
>       17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9811aef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
>       18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9811dfb9 start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   3/24/14 2:42:06.386 PM Mail[2601]: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)

I'm hoping we don't get to #3 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an Issue with writing permissions. You could:

1. check the 'console.app' for info-/error-entries and post them here for further analysis
2. run 'disk utility.app' and check the permissions on your HD and post the Infos here for further analysis
3. Quit Apple Mail and move the Folder 'V3' in `~Library/Mail/` to another place, like the Desktop, and start Apple Mail again. Your Mailbox will be downloaded again and the V3 Folder will be recreated, but should be simply updated the next time you start Apple Mail again.

Comment: You should really try #3 next. If you just move the V3 Folder somewhere and it still dosen't work, you can just move it back.

Comment: I dont' have a V3 folder - I have a V2 folder. Insight?

Comment: Typo on my part - my folder is called V2 too, so move that.

Comment: That sort of worked. Now my pop-account email has zero emails in it b/c they were popped already so are no longer on the server. Also my local mailfolders that had stuff in them are gone too. OTOH mail does not Welcome me each time.

Comment: ok, since you are using POP-Accounts you can copy back the contents of the folder beginning with 'pop-' into the newly created V2-Folder at '~/Library/Mail/'. You have to be careful and move the content of each 'POP'-Folder, so that you don't overwrite the new E-Mails you got by simply copying the POP-Folders. In any case a Backup is advised. After copying restart Mail and all the old Mails should be    restored.

Comment: Other things are gone too - smart folders saved to my tool bar is greyed-out / non-non functional.

Comment: My local folders are gone too

Comment: Did you move the Items back?

Comment: I moved the POP-Account-folder contents back - which one is the local folders and the smart searches?

Comment: local folders are stored in '~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes'. Smart Mailboxes are stored in "SmartMailboxes.plist", "SyncedSmartMailboxes.plist" and "SmartMailboxesLocalProperties.plist" in '~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData'